# Longest matching prefix of multi-word terms Bloom Filter

Tags: java, string-matching, bloom-filter

I have an implementation of a Bloom Filter in Java which serves as a dictionary/checker. However, I found it most optimal for my application to find the longest matching prefix of multi-word terms.

For example, in my Bloom Filter I have following words:

```
{'mac', 'macbook', 'macbookpro'}
```

After some text analysis I have discovered that people tend to vary the way they write a certain word, for example

```
'I love my mac book pro' or 'I love my MacBook Pro' or 'I love my macbookpro'
```

Now for me to process such sentences, I would check each word individually if this is in the Bloom Filter or not. If not, I wish to filter this word out. So for example

```
I -> no
love -> no
my -> no
```

But now comes the tricky part. 'Mac' is certainly in the dictionary, but so is 'macbook' and better is even 'macbookpro'

```
mac -> yes
book -> no
pro -> no
macbook -> yes
macbookpro -> yes
```

since 'macbookpro' is the longest, I wish to have this word as final output.

Is there some algorithm or efficient methodology in order for me to accomplish this with a Bloom Filter?

**Edit**
One needs to observe that such multi-word term does not necessarily need to be a match first followed by possible mismatched in order to be the longest word.

Example, in my dictionary there are only the words `{'macbook', 'macbookpro'}`

I have a sentence `'I love my mac book pro'`

Here the word `'mac'` will first result in a mismatch, however `'macbook'` and `'macbookpro'` WILL have a match.

Comment: How many of these "compound words" do you have in your dictionary, and do you know what they all are ahead of time? Also, is it OK if "macbookpro" doesn't match in a sentence like "I love my Macbo OK Pro"?

Comment: @JasonC somewhere around +100,000 words. And no I can say with 100% confident that such sentences will not occur.

Comment: The thing is, a Bloom filter is ultimately just a basic operation on a set: Given the set and an item, determine if the item is probably in the set or definitely not in it. The filter itself doesn't really have the means to do anything beyond that. Your issue kind of boils down to finding a way to determine possible combinations of words *before* handing them off to the filter (in other words, your items may not be purely whitespace delimited).

Comment: (continued) I know this isn't a solution but maybe it will at least give you some ideas to think about. Basically you want to identify word sequences that may form compound words first, *then* check the combinations against the filter.

Comment: @JasonC Indeed, I already did some experiments equivalent to your approach. The words in the Bloom Filter often have hyphens (eg., macbook-pro) Before adding them to the Bloom Filter, I remove these hyphens. Next I tried to make an algorithm that allows a window of 3 terms (meaning that 3 mismatches are allowed to be made before deciding the word is not a prefix).

Comment: What if you had a separate set, also possibly accessible via Bloom filter, that contained the possible first components of compound words as well as information about what words could follow? You add "mac -> book -> pro", "macbook -> pro", then as you iterate through words you look in that set. Say you are on "mac". You look it up. You find it. You obtain the possible compound sequence "book -> pro". You check if the next words in the sentence match that sequence. If they do, combine and consume them then proceed to look up "macbookpro" in your real set.

Comment: (That way you're not blindly checking 3 word windows, but the expense is an extra Bloom lookup in a smaller set for every word in order to determine if you should check if it starts a compound sequence. Minimal extra logic required to handle e.g. both "mac -> book" and "mac -> book -> pro" possibilities.)

Comment: @JasonC The idea sounds that it could help resolve my problem, however I can not clearly see how you should do that. Do you mean to have a second Bloom Filter with words such as "mac -> book -> pro" or do you mean a HashSet (or what ever) that contains tuples {word, info. about words}?

Comment: What Bloom filter implementation are you using? Guava?

Comment: @JasonC I have found [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/bloom_filter_java.shtml) implementation best suited for my needs.

Comment: Then I mean a `HashMap` (or what ever) that contains *first word in compound sequence -> info about following words in a compound sequence*. You could hash the first words themselves into a separate Bloom filter but I'm not sure that would help on the performance side.

Comment: Another alternative, along these lines might be, instead of having to have a HashMap of possible compound words, you could simply have a second Bloom filter that you dump all first words in. Then for each word in your sentence, you look it up in there. If it's definitely not in the filter, you proceed as normal, but if it might be in the filter, you do your 1-3 word window combination lookup in the master filter. I think that would give you better performance than a hash table lookup, given that compound words are rare; plus you dont have to load all compound words in a map first.

Comment: But since space is a big issue here, and was the reason I went for a Bloom Filter in the first place, having a HashMap will eat memory again.

Comment: Actually, I think that's a way better idea than the whole HashMap compound word thing.

Comment: Apologies I posted my answer before seeing your latest reply. But indeed that could be a better idea. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the idea in my previous comment wouldn't require another map. You're essentially just setting up a second bloom filter that determines if you do your windowed compound word guesses. So you load the second filter with e.g. "mac" and "macbook", you encounter them in a sentence, you see that they *might start compound words*, then you just try the window thing.

Comment: @JasonC I came across a minor issue. How can I determine if a word is a compound word? If for example the word `mac` is not in my filter but `macbook` and `macbookpro` is. What happens for the word `mac` in the sentence `i love my mac book pro`. This is what I actually discussed in my edit, it's possible a word is not in the filter BUT can possible be a prefix of a longer word that IS in the filter.